# Bootstrap Nesting Columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I'm attempting to recreate [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tvso.png) and can't seem to get the prices to line up as such. I believe I'm supposed to nest the columns, but can't seem to figure it out. It currently does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pmjr.png). Thanks in advance!

```css
.special-1 {
  color: black;
  float: left;
}
.special-2 {
  float: right;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row special-1">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
     <h3 class="center">Lunch Special</h3>
     <p class="center">11:00am - 3:00pm<br>No Soup for Take Out Orders<br>Served with Pork Fried Rice, Spring Roll, Egg Flower Soup, or Hot Sour Soup</p>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <p>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <p>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx</p>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row special-2">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
     <h3 class="center">Dinner Special</h3>
     <p class="center">3:00pm - Closing<br>No Soup for Take Out Orders<br></p>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <p>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <p>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx<br>xxx $x.xx</p>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually nested anything.

You have row/column/row/column END row/column/row/column END when you need these to work together as one, not completely separated.

See working example at FullPage and Docs [Nested Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

```css
.special {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container special">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <h3 class="text-center">Lunch Special</h3>
      <p class="text-center">11:00am - 3:00pm
        <br>No Soup for Take Out Orders
        <br>Served with Pork Fried Rice, Spring Roll, Egg Flower Soup, or Hot Sour Soup</p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3 class="text-center">Dinner Special</h3>
      <p class="text-center">3:00pm - Closing
        <br>No Soup for Take Out Orders
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx
            <br>xxx $x.xx</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange, when I run it throw StackOverflow it works fine, but once i drop it into my code, it goes back to being stacked vertically

Comment: Odd, the first things that come to mind are if you have any changes in your CSS that are altering Bootstraps core CSS or maybe try clearing your browser cache.